# Select all rows where Column which contains X is equal to yes

Tags: excel

I've got a load of columns with names in one of the rows and then yes/no in the rows below those names.

Does anyone know how I can create a dropdown menu which lists all those names.  Then when I select a name, it returns all the rows which have a yes in them for that column?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Filter - Autofilter (on the data menu)

Comment: Unfortunately I have a lot of these columns so I would need to go through each column and select no and then yes in the one I only want the information for.  With the amount of columns I have, it will become very time consuming

Comment: What would be good is if I had a dropdown list of all the data which was in a row 3 on all the columns with the names.  Then when I select the name it applies the filter across the board automatically